# Bundle multiple web-fonts to single file

Tags: bundle, webfonts

I'm using four different webfonts (all from the same family, all woff2-files) on a website and I would like to bundle them into a single file to reduce requests.

Is there any way to pack them together?

Comment: Same family but different font weight?